# Protocol Extension where Self is ClassA OR ClassB

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a protocol for which I want to provide default functionality in the case that the conforming class is either `ClassA` **OR** `ClassB`. Is it possible to use `||` in a protocol extension where clause? I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
extension Protocol where Self: ClassA || Self: ClassB {
    func method() {
        // implementation if conforming class is ClassA OR ClassB
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work, do you get an error message?

Comment: No, the syntax just isn't recognized

Comment: You can't – define a protocol instead to which both classes conform, and use `where Self: CommonProtocol`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use `||` (or something equivalent) in the `where` clause of a protocol extension.

If the extension method needs certain functionality which is present in both `ClassA` and `ClassB` then you can define that in a protocol  (to which both classes conform), and constrain the extension to that protocol.

Comment: Thank you. I realize now that this is the only way it could be because the extension would have no way to determine if you’re referring to ClassA or ClassB, so you need a protocol to define their commonalities.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply not possible at the moment. One solution could be creating two different extensions.

```swift
extension Protocol where Self: ClassA {
    func method() {
        commonMethod()
    }
}

extension Protocol where Self: ClassB {
    func method() {
        commonMethod()
    }
}

private func commonMethod() {
    // do here your stuff
}
```

Or creating a common protocol, assuming that `ClassA` and `ClassB` conform to this one.

```swift
protocol CommonProtocol {}

class ClassA: Protocol, CommonProtocol {}

class ClassB: Protocol, CommonProtocol {}

extension Protocol where Self: CommonProtocol {
    func method() {
       // your stuff
    }
}
```